# Solving equations having both log and exponential forms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

How can one Solve equations having both log and exponential forms:
For eg...

$e^x$ $=$ $\log_{0.001}(x)$ gives $x=0.000993$

(according to wolfram-alpha http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5Ex%3D+log0.001%28x%29)

It gives a graph of:
[Plot from wolfram-alpha http://www4a.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP5251h935h9i8a9g8050000056c4ic9h09c2e05b?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=34&w=423.&h=195.&cdf=Coordinates&cdf=Tooltips](http://www4a.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP5251h935h9i8a9g8050000056c4ic9h09c2e05b?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=34&w=423.&h=195.&cdf=Coordinates&cdf=Tooltips)

So can anyone please help me solve it?

Thanks

Comment: You could try using Lagrange Inversion Theorem

Answer (score 1):

First, let's change the base of the logarithm to $e$.

$$e^x=\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(0.001)}$$

Try solving for the $x$ inside the logarithm.

$$x=e^{\ln(0.001)e^x}=e^{e^{x+\ln(\ln(0.001))}}=f(f(x))$$

Try to find the mystery function $f(x)$?  If it such existed...

Then we'd have

$$x=f(f(x))$$Which has **some** solutions from solving the easier problem

$$x=f(x)$$

However, since I don't think there is a function $f(x)$, no closed form solution for $x$ will exist.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any way to solve this exactly. Even Wolfram-Alpha gives only a numerical solution (the other algebraic answers are just ways of transforming the question into other forms). Multiple numeric methods would work here--just choose your favorite.

Comment: It is taking the form of:
e^(-6.9e^(x))=x

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't much you can do. But here's something that *might* help. Let $y=e^x$. Clearly $$y=\log_{0.001}(x)$$ Which is the same as saying that $$x=0.001^y$$
And so your one equation is the same as solving the system of equations

$$\begin{cases}y=e^x\\x=0.001^y\end{cases}$$

Comment: Yeah but i don't think it will help much since when we put back y as e^x we get x=0.001^e^x